# Cannot SSH access Azure VM after persitenly mount File Share(storage account)

Tags: azure, mount, azure-storage-account

I've got an issue: after I create a persistent mount point following instructions in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-linux and rebooting my VM, I cannot SSH access my VM, any idea to fix?

Comment: Does SSH service running? Can you telnet it?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this could be a two way issue, a VM credential issue, or a problem from the node you are using to connect to the VM. This article refers to how to troubleshoot the VM side on Azure: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/troubleshoot-rdp-connection 
TLDR from the link:

```
Quick troubleshooting steps
After each troubleshooting step, try reconnecting to the VM:
Reset Remote Desktop configuration.
Check Network Security Group rules / Cloud Services endpoints.
Review VM console logs.
Reset the NIC for the VM.
Check the VM Resource Health.
Reset your VM password.
Restart your VM.
Redeploy your VM.
```

I'd suggest also trying to ssh from/to different nodes to check where the problem is, VM or starting point.